# Finding files with .plt extension using Windows Search

Tags: windows-7, windows-search, windows-sbs

We are using a SBS11 server and multiple Windows 7 clients. On a network drive, which is located at the server we have also *.plt files. Some of them could be found using Windows Search but most of them aren't showing up even if you copy paste the name of the file. After we noticed this problem we've add the .plt extension to the Windows Search Engine. After restarting the Windows Search Service nothing changed. We have also some files with the same name, but a different extenision, which could be found.

Comment: are they autocad files?

Comment: yes, some are marked as plt-autocad and other only as plt-file. But all are printed from autocad. And have the same extension.

Comment: Is the drive indexed? Does the user performing the search have access to all the locations?

Comment: Only the folder and its subfolders are indexed and yes the users have access to these locations.